# android - Develop apps using Visual Basic

Tags: android, vb.net

is it possible to develop android apps using Visual Basic? if yes, how?

i have been working with it for a while and eclipse is quite difficult to use. i'd seriously prefer using VS

Answer (score 1):

MSDN has a fairly useful [library article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn771552.aspx%22article%22) about cross-platform development in Visual Studio with links on how to install and use the Xamarin or Apache Cordova tools.

Xamarin seems to only support C#, but maybe you could look at using a tool such as [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/%22ILSpy%22) to decompile a binary created from VB into C#

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to develop android apps using VB.Net and Xamarin.Forms.

Xamarin allows you to develop cross platform apps using .Net framework - however, Xamarin users in most cases use C#.

Source - [Xamarin.Forms using Visual Basic.Net](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/pcl/portable_visual_basic_net/xamarin-forms/)

Answer (score 0):

Another way would be using ionic framework, cordova or phonegap (pretty much the same, with different GUI's).

You will code the app in JS, HTML and CSS and can compile it as native app for iOs, Android and other devices.

You can read more [here](http://ionicframework.com/)

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible yes, but I'd recommend you to take a look at [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

It's a very nice IDE using Java to develop android applications.

You can also use [Intel XDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-xdk). Very easy to use and flexible in choosing a framework, like [Ionic](http://ionicframework.com/) or [Jquery Mobile](https://jquerymobile.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can develop Android apps using Visual Basic.  Look at the product called "B4A" (Basic4Android) by Anywhere Software.

It's basically like developing in VB6 for Android, and has built-in visual designers and emulation connectivity.  You write all code in BASIC and it compiles down to native Java and APK files.  No special frameworks or runtimes are required.  Unlimited in its capabilities due to its ability to use Java code in modules (if desired), it's a truly amazing product.  it's also as popular as ever.  100% of the code you write will be in BASIC - NO JAVA, C#, or anything else).   If you ever want to know where all the VB developers went, now you know.

You're welcome.  :-)